# Sending E-Mail in C# using mail adresses from database

Tags: c#, sql, linq, email

I want to send e-mail in C# and use the mail addresses in the MySQL database. I am totally a beginner by the way. This is what i did so far :

I created a method for sending e mail:

```
public static void sendEmail()
{
    DataClassesDataContext dc = DataContext;         


    var _userMail = (from u in dc.Users
                       select u.Email).ToString();

    foreach (var item in _userMail)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add(_userMail);
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
        mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
```

And i am calling this method in one of my forms :

```
try
{
    AppMethod.sendEmail();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I wanted to take all mails from User table with using the `_userMail` and that's why I convert it to string. What should i do ? I mean where my mistake is, i couldnt find.

Comment: Well, what happens?  Do you get an error?  Does your code not compile?  Do you just get no results?  You need to specify what your problem actually is.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that Item contain your email Id then you can use below menioned code 
and if you want collection of mails then your query should be

```
 var _userMail = dc.Users.Select(p=>p.Email);
```

just replace

```
mail.To.Add(_userMail);
```

to

```
mail.To.Add(item);
```

if Item is Object of User then you have to tried below mentioned code

```
 mail.To.Add(item.emailId);
```

Comment: No actually that is what i was trying to do . How can i store that mail adresses? I guess i used foreach structure incorrect. What should i do to make contain email id in item? Or what if i wouldnt use the foreach structure?

Comment: you have just iterate a foreach loop and take one bye one email id from _userMail and send mail

Comment: so do i need to remove item and add _userMail inside the loop instead of loop? Because to be honest i dont know where does come from that item? I just looked how to use foreach and i thought that "item" represent the values inside of Users automaticly. :( I feel pretty stupid now.

Comment: I think you have to debugg your prog and see what's come in _userMail if it's contain email id then you don't need a foreach loop

Comment: I debugged without foreach loop and i got this error message: "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."

Comment: ok do one thing remove  var _userMail = (from u in dc.Users
                       select u.Email).ToString(); and write this  var _userMail = dc.Users.Select(p=>p.Email); and try with foreach

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' to 'string' That is what i got as an error. I guess i have to convert the values to string but how? Do i need a method for this or else?

Comment: have you used foreach loop for _userMail ?

Comment: Yes i did. My mind is so confused now. How can i get the e-mails from database ?